# T-sql Cursor, what will happen in case of error?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What will happen if an error occurs during:

1. Declaring a cursor
2. Fetching data

What will happen if the error occurs before the cursor is closed? Does it close automatically?

When I use a cursor, what is the best practice for handling errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an error occurs after declaring the cursor and the batch terminates, the cursor will remain open.  The cursor will be closed after the connection is closed.

If you can capture the error, it is good practice to close the cursor as part of the error handling.

Comment: How to close the cursor in case of error? I tried to use 'break' if @@error > 0 but it is not working

Answer (score 2):

**Updated with a better solution**

The `[CURSOR_STATUS][1]` function can be used to check the state of a cursor.

In SQL 2005 and later, this can be wrapped in a `TRY...CATCH` block.
Something like

```
BEGIN TRY

    DECLARE <cursorName>... CURSOR FOR
    ...cursor statement, fetch block, close & deallocate

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    IF (CURSOR_STATUS('global', '<cursorName>') > -2)
    DEALLOCATE dbCursor

    ...other error handling

END CATCH
```

Comment: Updated with a better solution; alsoe attempted to make the example clearer

Comment: Why > -2? I think you want to close it if status >= 0.

Comment: @Trevor - the code is deallocating the cursor, which is a distinct action from closing it. Dellocation frees the resources held by the cursor. Any status >-2 will require deallocation. See the command reference for `CURSOR_STATUS` referenced in the answer.